# how can i explicitly request data on POST

Tags: django, tastypie

I am familiar that i can set `always_return_data` to `True` to have the server return the serialized data back on `POST` and `PUT` requests. But is there a way i can specifically ask for the data to be returned on a particular `POST` call  and not all `POST/PUT` calls ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest adding an extra parameter to the post on which you want data returned. If the parameter exists in the post variables add the required data to the bundle in dehydrate

Answer (score 2):

You could set `always_return_data` to `True` and manually remove all the data from your bundle in either the `dehydrate` or the `alter_detail_data_to_serialize`method but that would just lead to an empty JSON (or whatever serialization you prefer) object to be returned, which is not exactly an empty response.

The probably most explicit way to the wanted behavior would be to override the `<method>_list`and `<method>_detail` functions and implement the decision whether to return data or not according to your needs.

Here's an example of `post_list` that takes a GET-Parameter named `return_data` to decide:

```
def post_list(self, request, **kwargs):
    deserialized = self.deserialize(request, request.raw_post_data, format=request.META.get('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json'))
    deserialized = self.alter_deserialized_detail_data(request, deserialized)
    bundle = self.build_bundle(data=dict_strip_unicode_keys(deserialized), request=request)
    updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
    location = self.get_resource_uri(updated_bundle)

    return_data = updated_bundle.request.GET.get('return_data', None)

    if not return_data is None:
        updated_bundle = self.full_dehydrate(updated_bundle)
        updated_bundle = self.alter_detail_data_to_serialize(request, updated_bundle)
        return self.create_response(request, updated_bundle, response_class=http.HttpCreated, location=location)
    else:    
        return http.HttpCreated(location=location)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion best way is to override dehydrate method and set always_return_data=True:

```
class SomeModelResource(ModelResource):
   class Meta:
      queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()
      always_return_data=True

   def dehydrate(self, bundle):
      if  request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and\
                  request.POST.get('param', None)=='PARAM':
           bundle.data = dict(id=bundle.obj.pk,
                               name=bundle.obj.name)
      return bundle
```